# Using alamofire how get response as raw string

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Using Alamofire library in my project. In case failure I want get all possible information from server why, not only Error object made by Alamofire, but full raw string or json. How I can get it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Here is a Demo on the Alamofire Official website. You can get all the JSON or string from your server as `response.response.data`, even if the request gets an error.

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").response { response in
    print("Request: \(response.request)")
    print("Response: \(response.response)")
    print("Error: \(response.error)")
    print("Timeline: \(response.timeline)")

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
    }
}
```

The response.error is used for simplifying your code.

Comment: This causes an error. You need to change “request in” to “response in”